# Create object with nested conditional type based on enum

Tags: typescript

I want to use the following type in my project:

```js
type MyObjectType = {
    vtype: "text";
    vvalues: string[];
} | {
    vtype: "num1";
    vvalues: number[];
} | {
    vtype: "num2";
    vvalues: number[];
}
```

I managed to define this type based on an enum like this

```js
enum MyValues {
    TEXT = 'text',
    NUM1 = 'num1',
    NUM2 = 'num2'
}
type MyValueTypes = `${MyValues}`

type MyValue<T extends MyValueTypes> =
    T extends 'num1' | 'num2' ? number :
    T extends 'text' ? string :
    never;

type ObjImpl<T> =
    T extends MyValueTypes ? {
        vtype: T;
        vvalues: MyValue<T>[];
    } : never;

type MyObjectType = ObjImpl<MyValueTypes>;
```

which constructs the exact type above.

However, I have problems with instantiating an object with this type using an enum value and a value of the corresponding type. How can I do this?

Here is what I tried to do:

```js
function fillProps<T extends MyValueTypes>(vtype: T, item: MyValue<T>): MyObjectType {
    return {
        vtype,
        // ERROR: Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[] | number[]'.
        vvalues: [item]
    }
}

fillProps(MyValues.TEXT, 78) // ERROR: ok
fillProps(MyValues.NUM1, 78) // ok
fillProps(MyValues.TEXT, 'asd') // ok
fillProps(MyValues.NUM2, 'asd') // ERROR: ok
```

[The full playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngNQIYBszAM5QN4FgBQURUAKgKIAaJUAvFAOQAuwAHo-QDQHFQByAqjACMtBuAhDO3YgJgAmUfXFz6BAL4FGcAA7BYiVOhI7MogAYASbPGRpMaswU0n9t9AB5qrZiAAmWG0NgY10MAD5aaSIvNlB-MUhJKAAfBIgVKAB+KHEAI2AAJygALijSKG84rCZveiyoDEYCgEsQAHMSspBgADdCgG4nfC1dKAB5XIArAEkIbRRPCJoymJ94wLsQ02y8Qh5iHpHgYtJBvf2oHp6gjBONjxIwgG0AXTOeNRKc3oHnUfgJpNgABjRhbUSA2bzdz3YImcJnAD0ACo-noAVMQWCXHRdjxDiYTgAiZhsInvA7XOy3BpNVptV5nT6pPEHI7E8RCcllK43E55QqM9QpHA89lQInKbnnS5U9A0gUFIX4DSEZGIoYAMzAIFBzQA9iAoJrmigUAAFAr67QYTwVWJ+AIGTbwsIACgJuhOJA4UGazAgd2dDzCAEog4CseDWUQCsBGGACkaY-tPcAuDKeIjEVAyAAlPNjPPelz0N2NFrtEWK0OvOrNLAgfWMKBIDAYZptEBIXIoPSMfVQI4MCv017VyD5JUvegAOjK+LlmBOT39wAgLzKqtVBBNZst1owbthGFn5CovoA7AAOUNQbO5gtFk76gDWu9NFqtNuPwcws9kIQr1ve8czfD992-I8TzPSgfQYNtfHoO8H3A-A9y-Q9fzcf9ZDkX16EQ5DQMfQtiygNCgA)

Comment: There are quite a number of issues with your code, so it would help if you'd [edit] to focus on a single one to work on, such as the `'T' only refers to a type` error.  Otherwise the answer will be a multi-page lecture on conditional types (you probably shouldn't be using them here), type erasure (`T` doesn't exist at runtime), and union correlation (why `vvalues` won't be seen as acceptable without a significant refactoring).  Which one do you want to tackle? (more...)

Comment: (...continued) If it's `vtype`, then the issue is one of type erasure, and you'll need to pass an actual value as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/NaDMBw). Would that constitute an answer to your question if written up? If so I'll do that (after the [edit]). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks! Yes it includes multiple problems. 'T' refer to type is the smallest one, I had several versions where I passed the vtype as value, but couldn't continue from there, thus I left it. I fix that one in the question because my focus would be filling the `vvalues`.

Comment: Then your issue is that TS can't analyze correlated unions as described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). Your options are either a type assertion like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxxr1m) or redundancy in your logic like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQ0aGW) or a type refactoring as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5xn0w). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write it up as an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly my issue, thank you!

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a single block of code like

```
return { vtype, vvalues: [item] }
```

the compiler can only analyze it once.  When you have multiple expressions inside that block that depend on a single [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) or a single [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a union type, the compiler will often lose track of the *correlation* between them.  It will treat them as independent even though they aren't.

And so you'll get an error where `vtype` is seen as "one of `MyValueTypes`" and `vvalues` is seen as "an array of `string` or `number`" without seeing that `vvalues` is "an array of the type that corresponds to `vtype`".

This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

---

There are various approaches you can take.  The easiest is just tell the compiler that you know what you're doing and it should calm down.  That is, you use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
function fillProps<T extends MyValueTypes>(vtype: T, item: MyValue<T>): MyObjectType {
    return {
        vtype,
        vvalues: [item] as string[] & number[]
    }
}
```

That's a lie, since `[item]` is not *both* a `string` array *and* a `number` array, but it silences the compiler error and lets you move on.

---

Or you could write a bunch of redundant code to lead the compiler through the different cases; that is, don't use a single block of code at all, but one block per possibility:

```
function fillProps<T extends MyValueTypes>(vtype: T, item: MyValue<T>): MyObjectType {
    if (vtype === "text") {
        if (typeof item !== "string") throw new Error();
        return { vtype, vvalues: [item] };
    }
    if (typeof item !== "number") throw new Error();
    return { vtype, vvalues: [item] };
}
```

---

Finally, you could use the approach described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), where you refactor to express all operations in terms of some basic mapping type, as well as generic [indexes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into that type or into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that type.

It would look like this:

```
interface MyValueMap {
    text: string;
    num1: number;
    num2: number;
}

type MyValue<K extends MyValueTypes> = MyValueMap[K]

type MyObjectType<K extends MyValueTypes = MyValueTypes> =
    { [P in K]: { vtype: P, vvalues: MyValueMap[P][] } }[K]

function fillProps<K extends MyValueTypes>(vtype: K, item: MyValue<K>): MyObjectType<K> {
    return { vtype, vvalues: [item] };
}
```

The `MyValueMap` is the basic mapping type which represents the relationship between `MyValueTypes` and the corresponding data type.  Then `MyValue<K>` is just an indexed access, and `MyObjectType<K>` is a *distributive object type* that takes a `K` and produces a union appropriate to it.  When you leave `K` out it [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `MyValueTypes` and thus `MyObjectType` is the same as your version.

And finally you make `fillProps` generic in `K` both in the input types and the output type.  Now the compiler sees `{vtype, vvalue:[item]}` as being of type `{vtype: K, vvalues: MyValueMap[K][]}` which is assignable to `MyObjectType<K>`.

This version is the closest you can get to being verified as type safe by the compiler.

---

Obviously your use cases will drive which of these three changes, if any, is best.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBKUICcAuSDeAsAFBKlITACuYSAsgJ4BqIANpdPsWd0gCoCiADV5IAvEgDk2CAA9sEgDRcepAHIBVWgEYxkqmC2LlKjbQBMuifrMTjSAL53s9GMgbM2EXi47iABgAkeO6s7FD2fsROPnRMoRAAPCKy0sAAJlCxHuzerlAAfGJ23MlyFBl61IZIAD6VYDZIAPxI+gBGWEgAXMVkpakVUikSzUhQ2JgAlsAA5t29pMAQAG5YANxRJGTOrkgA8m0AVgCSYDAsSYWiC3zkZemZIZ65HC2EWyrcyzsQXXwbH0+pGWy3iUD+T3YlwA2gBdAFA+zdVordbRXYMA6HCDwbAvXRY07nBKQrw+AoAzbcABmlGAuMmAHtgEhqZMWCwAAqYRkwKBJO4DR5xZ7k-IACm+Pj+vAUSEm0jAEJFUN4+QAlMqsTi8TF3kDMBBsJRMCz9UCyFLXEpAUCQWC-tCFRAwLCkCBMuMprM4UgAGStagdTBwm6OQHhuxsjnc3lQcWkqAAOgEwjlAHYABzqpAAelzSH4ACUi3si39GQBrKPsrk8vkJlXQJOmLQZ7N5gtVmsx+vxxMpoSyyQetISHP5pDdwHRutxxvZZumMxyiSj8edwslssV6tEYiRoigSCwBDIIsQNJ0tIgYC4c2kCjULJgzi2vpDyzSORGd9qTQ6OIVhVL+QLLpY1i2BG6JuE2LyZP4QSJhEVLbDEpICik5TCou8FXDc-TYfU1R1MBDQjC07SdD0f63FhDySN+8ijF60xzDRQJLKsmCUoCPz7EcRIXGqRS0YRDGkvBowPhaVq-P8NxfKCnjgi+ngwvCYbIlxaJ8eh9Dari+LiISZwXJJYq8VGdIMsyrK1rGfKYfcFQWXkEpyTKcrOkqamqhqWpHDq+IydwkzUkgkr8aIMVIAARExcU5qFnzhZFPyMhFPlIAAhLFcWsbMSVINgAAWPIAO4olV-CYDymDiuqCIWqQhrGqa+BIHJcr2ipjo+W69jNSo4ZAml4oZVliq5flVGYMVZWVdVhZ1YyDVNTcbUmmaXU-D1ylhP1iqDcNDioaQs6Of2TbJqmw5ZhOBbFqW5ZTnuNIOX2C5gi2AHto9b09nODYDndq7rgD04fb284Dsu4NQGOAPPTugP7ujB6bMe0BwIgSAXtSCDYGtb7cE+NCJqTnx3V+ww2mBAEQSB9OfOBQGQXYo1oRicHkrogTBDdKHo2Fd5YITeOkrQIAwFTKhMX8hUzKd3D6FofxzSrZDWBrQa6dwh7cPxGEANKCkRbnQFcfkQNLMDQibsLnSV+mGbqrgJGb9GubzeS6JbBSiUCeBINCnLyiyjt-CHnlIJy+0Ojbdth7CvpIvYDtOyLZC0vS2BMiyl19p75sSb7VtRdKSAm95irKounsBbEbsvI3cs8FtHUx3tXUHdAR0uidnPO0XsM3YOaZIA9m4o69UNkPAzLjEgABegXYkZMTiKPIPj62-2bvPF2fWPi63UOCNI4f705yfu9n795iXxuk6z7umz2EAA)

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! I'll use the mapping as it seems to be a better fit for my case than conditional types.